# How to remove specific marker from map and firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to android and I have followed this tutorial for real-time asset tracking.   [Tracking Url](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/realtime-asset-tracking/index.html#0)

Now, I want to delete marker from firebase as well as from app without any need to open firebase in the browser. How can I do it? Is it possible?

Below code is for the app which sends location updates to firebase server.

**TrackerService.java**

```
public class TrackerService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = TrackerService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {return null;}

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        loginToFirebase();
    }

private void loginToFirebase() {

        // Authenticate with Firebase, and request location updates
        String email = getString(R.string.firebase_email);
        String password = getString(R.string.firebase_password);

        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>(){
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "firebase auth success");
                    requestLocationUpdates();
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "firebase auth failed");
                }
            }
        });
    }

private void requestLocationUpdates() {

        LocationRequest request = new LocationRequest();
        request.setInterval(10000);
        request.setFastestInterval(5000);
        request.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        FusedLocationProviderClient client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        final String path = getString(R.string.firebase_path) + "/" + getString(R.string.transport_id);
        int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        if (permission == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Request location updates and when an update is 
            // received, store the location in Firebase

            client.requestLocationUpdates(request, new LocationCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(path);
                    Location location = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                    if (location != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "location update " + location);
                        ref.setValue(location);
                    }
                }
            }, null);
        }
    }
```

**Below code is from the second app which displays markers on the map.**

```
public class DisplayActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private static final String TAG = DisplayActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private HashMap<String, Marker> mMarkers = new HashMap<>();
    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        // Authenticate with Firebase when the Google map is loaded
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMaxZoomPreference(16);
        loginToFirebase();
    }

    private void loginToFirebase() {
        String email = getString(R.string.firebase_email);
        String password = getString(R.string.firebase_password);
        // Authenticate with Firebase and subscribe to updates
        FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
                email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    subscribeToUpdates();
                    Log.d(TAG, "firebase auth success");
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "firebase auth failed");
                }
            }
        });
    }

 private void subscribeToUpdates() {
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(getString(R.string.firebase_path));
        ref.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                setMarker(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
                setMarker(dataSnapshot);
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String previousChildName) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });
    }

    private void setMarker(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // When a location update is received, put or update
        // its value in mMarkers, which contains all the markers
        // for locations received, so that we can build the 
        // boundaries required to show them all on the map at once

        String key = dataSnapshot.getKey();
        HashMap<String, Object> value = (HashMap<String, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(value.get("latitude").toString());
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(value.get("longitude").toString());
        LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lng);

        if (!mMarkers.containsKey(key)) {
            mMarkers.put(key, mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().title(key).position(location)));
        } else {
            mMarkers.get(key).setPosition(location);
        }
        LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        for (Marker marker : mMarkers.values()) {
            builder.include(marker.getPosition());
        }
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 300));
    }
```

Comment: show the code you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app you create a way to select the marker you want to delete, using a button or selecting it directly from the map (I suggest the second way), then remove the marker from the mMarkers list, rebuild the markers in the map and remove the "document" from firebase.

For the Marker part you can follow some [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/marker) on the official documentation for maps and markers.

For the Firebase part check [how to remove data from RealTime Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write?authuser=0#delete_data), but basically you get the Database Reference for your data `DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(path)` and call removeValue from it `ref.removeValue()`

Comment: Thanks a lot buddy. The marker documentation helped a lot.